# Bash: Rename file name to unix timestamp of modification date

Tags: linux, bash, file, timestamp

Hello I need to rename files to their unix time stamp of their modification date and append it as a prefix.

In other words I need a script to mass rename
Files like

ABC.jpg

and

XYZ.png

to

1649493072000 ABC.jpg

1649493072182 XYZ.png

I also like to append a u- in front of every file that is modified this way.

SO I like to turn

ABC.jpg

and

XYZ.png

Into

u-1649493072000 ABC.jpg

u-1649493072182 XYZ.png

PS:

To all mods please note that my question is different from other questions already asked since I'm asking about the UNIX Modification timestamp of the file not the ISO date like 2022-04-09.

Comment: You have a space between the timestamp string and the original file name.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes it intentional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec \
sh -c '
for i do
    d=$(dirname "$i")
    [ "$d" = / ] && d=
    n=${i##*/}
    echo mv "$i" "$d/u-$(stat -c %Y "$i") $n"
done' _ {} +
```

- This operates recursively in the current directory (`.`). It only targets regular files (not directories etc). Modify `-type f` and other flags if needed.
- It just prints the mv commands, so you can review them. Remove the `echo` to run for real.
- We use `find` to list the target files, and its `-exec` flag to pass this list to a shell loop where we can parse and modify the filenames, including `stat` to get the modification time.
- I don't know your use case, but a better solution may be to just save the output of: `find . -type f -printf '%p u-%T@\n'` in a file, for later reference (this prints the file path and modification time on the same line). Also, maybe a snapshot (if possible).

Comment: Hmm. This script only prints out to the CMD text and is not executing the mv command 
"Also, maybe a snapshot (if possible)" Did you mean something like this https://imgur.com/a/wlG1DMV

Comment: See bullet point number 2 (remove `echo`). This is common practise for an example of a destructive command (`mv`).

Comment: By snapshot I mean an incremental backup. Via btrfs, zfs, rsync, etc.

Comment: Yep got it it works. Thanks. Is there a way to modify it so that it uses creation date ?

Comment: `man stat` yields `%W` for time of file birth (change `%Y` to `%W`). However, note that not all filesystems record file birth time.  See the first answer here for more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file

Comment: Thanks for all the help all works now. Only I do not know if you should put up non functional code on stackoverflow (remove the echo).

Comment: No worries. Like I said, it's a good (and common) practise for a _destructive_ command (`mv`). If there was some bug you could lose data. You should read the code and explanation (and understand it as much as you can) before running it.